# How to get the date/time now using Python?

Tags: boto3

How to get the date/time now using Python?

What does it mean to find the date/time using python

Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you edit an earlier SQS question (44013079) to repurpose it for a new Python date/time question?

Answer (score 1):

You can see the [body of the message](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/sqs.html#SQS.Message.body) with:

```
message.body
```

---

I usually do this with the following snippet:

```
REGION = 'us-west-2'  # or whichever


def main(queue_name):
    """Continuously poll the queue for messages (jobs)."""
    sqs = boto3.resource('sqs', region_name=REGION)
    queue = sqs.get_queue_by_name(QueueName=queue_name)
    while True:
        poll(queue=queue)

def poll(queue):
    messages = queue.receive_messages()  # Note: MaxNumberOfMessages default is 1.    
    for m in messages:
        process_message(m)

def process_message(message):
    print(message.body)
    # ...
    if success:  # processed ok
        message.delete()  # remove from queue
    else:  # an error of some kind
        message.change_visibility(VisibilityTimeout=1)  # dead letter or try again
```

Comment: @JoKo messages should definitely be in flight. :/

Comment: @JoKo so printing at each step is a good way. Since you are using python you can do this at the command line, rather than via a program. That's how I'd try to debug. i.e. `python` at the command line, follow the program at the prompt and try and get a message and poke at it...

Comment: @JoKo maybe another machine or process is doing the polling (is something running on the machine? check `ps -ef | grep python`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me. Here is the output (printing json.dumps(message, indent=4)) that I see if I run the code and then send a message to my SQS queue:

```
{
    "Messages": [
        {
            "Body": "Hello Jo Ko!",
            "ReceiptHandle": "redacted",
            "MD5OfBody": "redacted",
            "MessageId": "redacted"
        }
    ],
    "ResponseMetadata": {
        "RetryAttempts": 0,
        "HTTPStatusCode": 200,
        "RequestId": "redacted",
        "HTTPHeaders": {
            "x-amzn-requestid": "redacted",
            "content-length": "800",
            "server": "Server",
            "connection": "keep-alive",
            "date": "Wed, 17 May 2017 16:00:00 GMT",
            "content-type": "text/xml"
        }
    }
}
```

PS The botocore SQS [receive_message](http://botocore.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/sqs.html#SQS.Client.receive_message) method doesn't return a message. It returns a dict that contains an array of messages.

Comment: If you are seeing no messages then I would assume that either a) there are no messages or b) there are messages but they are "in flight" (which means that another client, e.g. the AWS console or another instance of your app, has received the messages and is processing them but has not yet deleted them (and the visibility timeout has yet to expire).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `datetime.now` for your local time. For UTC/EST/WIB etc., you may change the time format to epoch (unix) for time differences then put back the format you like afterwards.

```
from datetime import datetime

from datetime import timedelta



local_time = datetime.now()

utc_time = datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=8)

est_time = datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=12)

wib_time = datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=1)

pst_time = datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=9)

wat_time = datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=9)

fmt = '%a, %Y/%m/%d,%H:%M'
```